# Is there a way to tell Psych in ruby to using inline mode?

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

environment: ruby1.9.3 , psych(any version)
ex:

```
o = { 'hash' => { 'name' => 'Steve', 'foo' => 'bar' } } 
 => {"hash"=>{"name"=>"Steve", "foo"=>"bar"}} 

#is there a inline option?
puts Psych.dump(o,{:inline =>true})
```

real result:

```
---
hash:
  name: Steve
  foo: bar
```

expect output:

```
--- 
hash: { name: Steve, foo: bar }
```

Comment: I doubt that Psych supports this. The only thing an `ack -i inline` in LibYAML or the Psych sources yields is a parsing test for inline arrays and hashes. Why do you need this?

Comment: Because my hash is very much like tabular data. I want to see it more clearly and save monitor space.

Comment: I guess you're out of luck then. But you can always write it as CSV or something to a separate file to inspect it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have an object with hierarchical hash and array architecture. I want to dump it into a kind of text format(like YAML). And load it as ruby data later.

Comment: Why not save it as YAML and write a small Ruby script that parses and formats it so you can easily inspect it? This can be done in minutes, if not seconds.

Comment: @NiklasB : sorry, I am newbie in ruby. Can you give a example code ? thanks you very much. :D

Comment: What, for reading YAML and printing the output? If you have problems with that, please create a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Psych supports this, although it isn't at all straightforward.

I've started researching this in [my own question on how to dump strings using literal style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9640277/11687).

I ended up devising [a complete solution for setting various styles](https://gist.github.com/2023978) for specific objects, including inlining hashes and arrays.

With my script, a solution to your problem would be:

```
o = { 'hash' => StyledYAML.inline('name' => 'Steve', 'foo' => 'bar') }
StyledYAML.dump o, $stdout
```

Comment: hi and sorry. How to include styled_yaml.rb in my rails app? thanks.

Comment: Put it somewhere (e.g. "lib/"), then require it.

Answer (score 0):

The [representable](https://github.com/apotonick/representable#flow-style-lists) gem provides this in a convenient OOP style.

Considering you have a model User:

```
user.name => "Andrew"
user.age => "over 18"
```

You'd now define a representer module to render/parse User instances.

```
require 'representable/yaml'

module UserRepresenter
  include Representable::YAML

  collection :hash, :style => :flow

  def hash
    [name, age]
  end
end
```

After defining the YAML document you simply extend the user instance and render it.

```
user.extend(UserRepresenter).to_yaml
#=> ---
hash: [Andrew, over 18]
```

Hope that helps, Andrew!